# Could someone give me direction on how I would take a player object and move it throughout a 2D Array of Tile Objects?

Tags: java, oop, game-development

I have created an object, which is called Tile which has information about whats on its tile and what type of tile it is. I have then created a 2D Array of these Tile objects and looped the display procedure to output the grid as an ASCII grid in the console, the loop checks to see what is on the tile and will fill the associated grid square with a blank ect.

I was wondering if you could give me direction on how I can take a player object, and start to put it inside the grid as I am quite confused on where to start. I am curious as to how I can get Tiles.contains() to show me the player object so I can then start to perform functions against the object such as Player.moveLeft ect.

Thanks for your help!

I am quite confused where to even start here.

```
/**
 * @aim Tile Object which contains information about each grid square
 */

public class Tile 
{
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Class Variables
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private String szType;
    private boolean bIsEmpty;
    private String szOnTile;

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public Tile()
    {
        reset();
        return;
    }

    public Tile(String Type, boolean IsEmpty, String OnTile)
    {
        reset();
        setType(Type);
        setIsEmpty(IsEmpty);
        setOnTile(OnTile);
    }


    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Setters
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void setType(String Type)
    {
        this.szType = Type; 
        return;
    }

    public void setIsEmpty(boolean IsEmpty)
    {
        this.bIsEmpty = IsEmpty; 
        return;
    }

    public void setOnTile(String OnTile)
    {
        this.szOnTile = OnTile; 
        return;
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Getters
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public String getType()
    {
        return(this.szType);
    }

    public boolean getIsEmpty()
    {
        return(this.bIsEmpty);
    }

    public String getOnTile()
    {
        return(this.szOnTile);
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Utilities
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void displayObject()
    {
        System.out.println("Type = " + getType());
        System.out.println("IsEmpty = " + getIsEmpty());
        System.out.println("OnTile = " + getOnTile());
        System.out.println();
    }

    private void reset()
    {
        setType("Blank");
        setIsEmpty(true);
        setOnTile("None");
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Test-Rig
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {


    }
}
```

```
public class TestMap 
{

    public static final int iGRID_WIDTH = 10;
    public static final int iGRID_HEIGHT = 10;
    public static Tile[][] Map = new Tile[iGRID_HEIGHT][iGRID_WIDTH];

    public static void generateMap ()
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for(i = 0 ; i < iGRID_HEIGHT ; i++)
        {

            for(j = 0 ; j < iGRID_WIDTH ; j++)
            {

                Map[i][j] = new Tile();

            }
        }
        return;
    }

    public static void displayMap()
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;      

        System.out.println("---------------------");
        for(i = 0 ; i < iGRID_HEIGHT ; i++)
        {

            System.out.print("|");

            for(j = 0 ; j < iGRID_WIDTH ; j++)
            {
                if(Map[i][j].getOnTile() == "None")
                {
                    System.out.print("  " + "|");
                }   
            }

            System.out.print("\n");
            System.out.println("---------------------");
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        generateMap();
        displayMap();

    }

}
```

I want to be able to take a Player Object and begin to traverse it through the grid. I know how you would do this with a normal 2D array; but I'm confused on how to transfer this to a 2D Array of Objects. I am aware my Tile Object is not entirely in the rules of OOP it is still a work in progress.

EDIT:

I have now implemented the discussed changes (or tried to) and this is the results:

```
/**
 * @author Damien Newnham
 * @aim Tile Object which contains information about each grid square
 */

public class Tile implements TileObjectInterface
{
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Class Variables
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private String szType;
    private boolean bIsEmpty;
    private String szOnTile;

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public Tile()
    {
        reset();
        return;
    }

    public Tile(String Type)
    {
        reset();
        setType(Type);
    }


    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Setters
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void setType(String Type)
    {
        this.szType = Type; 
        return;
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Getters
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public String getType()
    {
        return(this.szType);
    }

    public boolean isObjectHere(TileObjectInterface searchingObject)
    {
        boolean isObjectHere = false;
        if(containedObjectList.contains(searchingObject) == true)
        {
            isObjectHere = true;
        }
        return isObjectHere;
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Utilities
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void displayObject()
    {
        System.out.println("Type = " + getType());
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void removeObject(TileObjectInterface implementingObject) 
    {
        containedObjectList.remove(implementingObject);
    }

    public void addObject(TileObjectInterface implementingObject) 
    {
        containedObjectList.add(implementingObject);
    }



    private void reset()
    {
        setType("Blank");
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Test-Rig
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {


    }

}
```

```
public class TestMap extends Globals
{

    public static void generateMap ()
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for(i = 0 ; i < iGRID_HEIGHT ; i++)
        {

            for(j = 0 ; j < iGRID_WIDTH ; j++)
            {

                Map[i][j] = new Tile();

            }
        }
        return;
    }

    public static void spawnPlayer()
    {
        Map[0][0].addObject(player);
    }

    public static void displayMap()
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;      

        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        for(i = 0 ; i < iGRID_HEIGHT ; i++)
        {

            System.out.print("|");

            for(j = 0 ; j < iGRID_WIDTH ; j++)
            {
                if(Map[i][j].isObjectHere(player) == true)
                {
                    System.out.print("XX" + "|");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print("  " + "|");
                }
            }

            System.out.print("\n");
            System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {


    }

}
```

```
public class PlayerMovementController extends Globals
{

    public static int iPlayerRow = 0;
    public static int iPlayerColumn = 0;

    public static void movePlayer(char chDirection)
    {
        chDirection = Character.toUpperCase(chDirection);

            if (chDirection == 'L')
            {
                Map[iPlayerRow][iPlayerColumn].removeObject(player);
                Map[iPlayerRow - 1][iPlayerColumn].addObject(player);
                iPlayerRow = iPlayerRow - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (chDirection == 'R')
                {
                    Map[iPlayerRow][iPlayerColumn].removeObject(player);
                    Map[iPlayerRow + 1][iPlayerColumn].addObject(player);
                    iPlayerRow = iPlayerRow + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (chDirection == 'U')
                    {
                        Map[iPlayerRow][iPlayerColumn].removeObject(player);
                        Map[iPlayerRow][iPlayerColumn - 1].addObject(player);
                        iPlayerColumn = iPlayerColumn - 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(chDirection == 'D') 
                        {
                            Map[iPlayerRow][iPlayerColumn].removeObject(player);
                            Map[iPlayerRow][iPlayerColumn + 1].addObject(player);
                            iPlayerColumn = iPlayerColumn + 1;
                        }
                    }

            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

    }

}
```

```
public class Globals 
{
    public static Player player = new Player("Damo");

    public static final int iGRID_WIDTH = 10;
    public static final int iGRID_HEIGHT = 10;
    public static Tile[][] Map = new Tile[iGRID_HEIGHT][iGRID_WIDTH];



    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

    }

}
```

```
public class TestRig 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        TestMap.generateMap();
        TestMap.spawnPlayer();
        TestMap.displayMap();

        PlayerMovementController.movePlayer('R');
        TestMap.displayMap();
        PlayerMovementController.movePlayer('R');
        TestMap.displayMap();

        PlayerMovementController.movePlayer('D');
        TestMap.displayMap();
        PlayerMovementController.movePlayer('L');
        TestMap.displayMap();
    }

}
```

```
/**
 * @author Damien Newnham
 * @aim Player Object which contains information about the player
 */

public class Player implements TileObjectInterface
{
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Class Variables
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private String szCharacterName;

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public Player()
    {
        reset();
        return;
    }

    public Player(String CharacterName)
    {
        reset();
        setCharacterName(CharacterName);
    }


    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Setters
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void setCharacterName(String CharacterName)
    {
        this.szCharacterName = CharacterName; 
        return;
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Getters
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public String getCharacterName()
    {
        return(this.szCharacterName);
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Utilities
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void displayObject()
    {
        System.out.println("CharacterName = " + getCharacterName());
        System.out.println();
    }

    private void reset()
    {
        setCharacterName("Bob");
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Test-Rig
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {


    }

}
```

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public interface TileObjectInterface 
{
    LinkedList<TileObjectInterface> containedObjectList = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

The issue now is a logical error or syntaxing error in the adding and removing of objects, the output is as shown below from running TestRig

```
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------



-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------



-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------



-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------



-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|XX|
-------------------------------
```

The desired output should be XX's in the top left cell on the first image, which then moves Right once, Right once again, Down Once, then Left Once. As seen it seems to display XX's in every cell.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to have a two dimensional array of Tile objects representing the map.
You might want to ask yourself whether the Tiles / Map should be capable of performing actions on the objects that they contain. Your implementation could be made more clear when you think of your Tile class as an container which can contain other objects.

The purpose of the class is to contain objects and remove / add new ones. So a good idea would be to abstract the contained objects in an interface. Each individual tile acts as a container of these objects implementing the interface.

This results in a data layer which has no additional purpose than holding the data related to the program (game). On top of this layer you can build a logic layer which can now use the datalayer to perform actions on it. The logic layer will contain your two dimensional array traversal.

Keep in mind that this is a very basic approach and you may want to abstract more once you extend your program.

### Update

[image: Class diagram showing the container]

Code example how this might be implemented in Java:

```
// in Tile class
// please consider renaming the interface etc. (just for clearance here)

LinkedList<TileObjectInterface> containedObjectList = new LinkedList<>();

// method example to add to the container (which is Tile)
// consider adding error checks

public void add(TileObjectInterface implementingObject) {
    this.containedObjectList.add(implementingObject);
}
```

I cannot answer your question on how you design your containers because this will depend on the usage later on. If you make a simple list implementation you might run into runtime class checks which is probably unwanted. But I can imagine that it would be possible to operate on the container when you are holding an external reference of for instance your player object.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195006/discussion-on-answer-by-crimsonmike-could-someone-give-me-direction-on-how-i-wou).